# Get all comments for handsontable table

Tags: javascript, handsontable

I'm using [handsontable](https://handsontable.com/) to paste data from excel. I want to add more information, a string representing a CSS class, to some cells. I thought that the best way will be to use the [comments](http://docs.handsontable.com/0.16.1/Comments.html) plugin.
There I see information about how to add comments, but I don't see how to read the comments.
When I tried:

```
hot1 = new Handsontable(container, {
    data: getData(),
    rowHeaders: true,
    colHeaders: true,
    contextMenu: true,
    comments: true,
    cell: [
      {row: 1, col: 1, comment: 'Some comment'},
      {row: 2, col: 2, comment: 'More comments'}
    ]
});      

hot1.getData();
```

I see only the table data without any information about the comments. From the documentation it look like I can access a specific cell to get it's comments but there is no reference if I can get all the comments in one command (similar to how I get the data).

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

We can get all comments using the `getCellMeta` method.

```
var comments = [];
hot1.getCellMeta().cell.forEach(allComments);
console.log(comments)

function allComments(element){
  comments.push(element.comment);
}
```

Here is a working [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hsk90/4hzmeabf/27/).

Comment: Is there any event that I can listen to in order to track all the comment changes? as you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4hzmeabf/28/) I have tried to add your function to the "afterChange" event, but this event is been called ONLY when I make a change to one of the cells and not when I'm adding / removing a comment

Answer (score 0):

@Shlomi L asked if there was an event that can be tied into to catch when comments change. Yes there is. It's called: afterSetCellMeta. Here is an example:

```
afterSetCellMeta:  (row, col, source, val)  => {
       if(source == 'comment'){
                    console.log("[" + row + ", " + col + "]: " + source + " --> " + val);
                        console.log(source); //comment
                        console.log(val); //object containing value
                        this.saveUpdatedComment(val.value);

                    }
  }
```

This will come before or after afterChange. Here are the [docs](https://docs.handsontable.com/0.15.1/Hooks.html#event:afterSetCellMeta)